# How to specify user defined archive directory for running "apt install ./<package_name>"

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have to do an installation of a few packages. The problem is the system will not have access to the internet. I can download all the dependent .deb files using

```
for i in $(apt-cache depends default-jre-headless | grep -E 'Depends|Recommends|Suggests' | cut -d ':' -f 2,3 | sed -e s/'<'/''/ -e s/'>'/''/); do apt-get download $i 2>>errors.txt; done
```

But when I try to install it using `apt install ./default-jre-headless` It does not search the local directory and goes online.

Is there any way to provide directory location for all .deb file to apt install command??

Or else a better solution would also be a great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I found the solution but forgot to mention here.

In order to make the local directory path for deb files and dependencies. We have to first download all the dependencies in any folder and after that run this command.

```
echo "Dir::Cache::Archives "/opt/packages/dep/";" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

EDIT:
Extending the answer for a better solution:
Host the deb file on an Nginx Docker container. And Copy files from Ubuntu/CentOS image in the Nginx container.

Check out this gist: It has the Dockerfile for creating a dependent deb/rpm files in the image and moving it into an Nginx container. If you have some extra zip or tar file, it can also be included. Also, it has a conf file for reference. 
https://gist.github.com/ismail0352/e96d2cc94b71ef2324c9c0890ef7ca7f

A small part of it for reference:

```
# For Ubuntu
FROM ubuntu as ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y dpkg-dev wget gnupg2 curl
WORKDIR /opt/packages/deb
RUN apt update

RUN chown -R _apt /opt/packages/deb/

RUN apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-enhances default-jre-headles | grep "^\w" | sort -u)

RUN dpkg-scanpackages . | gzip -9c > Packages.gz

# For Centos
FROM centos as centos
WORKDIR /opt/packages/rpm
RUN yum install wget curl epel-release createrepo yum-utils -y
RUN yum update -y

RUN yumdownloader --resolve java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless

# Nginx
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt install wget -y

COPY nginx_default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=ubuntu /opt/packages/ .

COPY --from=centos /opt/packages/ .

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/others/

RUN wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash/logstash-7.3.1.zip
```